# group by and find index of first non-zero in each group in data table

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, data.table

I have a data table in R, that looks like:

```
   city year target
1:  NYC 2000      0
2:  NYC 2000      1
3:  NYC 2000      1
4:   LA 2000      0
5:   LA 2000      0
6:   LA 2000      1
7:   LA 2000      1
```

which can be created by:

```
data = data.table(city = c("NYC", "NYC", "NYC", "LA", "LA", "LA", "LA"),
                  year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000),
                  target = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1))
```

I would like to group them by `city` and `year` and find index of the first nonzero element in column `target`so I can modify it, the desired result should look like:

```
   city year target
1:  NYC 2000      0
2:  NYC 2000    666
3:  NYC 2000      1
4:   LA 2000      0
5:   LA 2000      0
6:   LA 2000    666
7:   LA 2000      1
```

any help is appreciated.

The following does not work:

```
cutoff_thresh <- function(x, cutoff) {x > cutoff}

helper <- data %>% 
          group_by(city, year) %>%
          mutate(thresh = detect_index(.x = target,
                 .f = cutoff_thresh,
                  cutoff = 0)
                 )
```

It produces the exact day of a given year that the first non-zero element occurs,
it starts counting at the first day of each year. So, if 2000 has 365 days in it, and the 2nd day of 2001 we is non-zero, it returns `2` for `(NYC, 2001)` as opposed to `365 + 2`. Not surprisingly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the dataset is already a `data.table`, it may be more efficient to use `data.table` methods.  Grouped by 'city', 'year', get the row index (`.I`) of first non-zero element ('i1'), use that in `i` and assign (`:=`) the value of 'target' to 666

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- data[, .I[target != 0][1], .(city, year)]$V1
data[i1, target := 666][]
#    city year target
#1:  NYC 2000      0
#2:  NYC 2000    666
#3:  NYC 2000      1
#4:   LA 2000      0
#5:   LA 2000      0
#6:   LA 2000    666
#7:   LA 2000      1
```

---

An option using `tidyverse` would be

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
   group_by(city, year) %>% 
   mutate(target = replace(target, which(target != 0)[1], 666))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   city, year [2]
#  city   year target
#  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 NYC    2000      0
#2 NYC    2000    666
#3 NYC    2000      1
#4 LA     2000      0
#5 LA     2000      0
#6 LA     2000    666
#7 LA     2000      1
```

Or with `match`

```
data %>% 
   group_by(city, year) %>%
   mutate(target = replace(target, match(1, target), 666))
```

NOTE: All the solutions work even if there is no 1's in the 'target' for a particular group

e.g.

```
data$target[6:7] <- 0
data %>%
    group_by(city, year) %>% 
    mutate(target = replace(target, which(target != 0)[1], 666))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   city, year [2]
#  city   year target
#  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 NYC    2000      0
#2 NYC    2000    666
#3 NYC    2000      1
#4 LA     2000      0
#5 LA     2000      0
#6 LA     2000      0
#7 LA     2000      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` you can find the index of first non-zero element using `which.max` in the group and `replace` it by 666.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(city, year) %>%
  mutate(target = replace(target, which.max(target != 0), 666))


#  city   year target
#  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 NYC    2000      0
#2 NYC    2000    666
#3 NYC    2000      1
#4 LA     2000      0
#5 LA     2000      0
#6 LA     2000    666
#7 LA     2000      1
```

You can also use the same thing with `ifelse`

```
data %>%
  group_by(city, year) %>%
  mutate(target = ifelse(row_number() == which.max(target != 0), 666, target))
```

Comment: Nice trick, to use `which.max` to find the first non-zero element.

Comment: Another `data.table` way using `replace` similar to your first approach: `data[, target := replace(target, cumsum(target != 0) == 1L, 666L), by = .(city, year)][]`

Answer (score 1):

With data.table, join with the mult= argument to edit only the first row meeting the join criteria (if any)

```
> data[.(unique(city), 1), on=.(city, target), mult="first", target := 999]
> data
   city year target
1:  NYC 2000      0
2:  NYC 2000    999
3:  NYC 2000      1
4:   LA 2000      0
5:   LA 2000      0
6:   LA 2000    999
7:   LA 2000      1
```